# MySQL memory leak?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04, memory-usage, memory-leak

I've just installed a brand new server image, and have been finding that MySQL has been consuming a lot of memory despite the fact that nobody's been querying it. I checked `free -m` to see if it was a matter of cache (à la http://www.linuxatemyram.com/), but it wouldn't appear to be.  I've tried restarting the service, and the same amount of memory is used. I am running Ubuntu 12.04. Is this a memory leak? How can I fix this?

`# free -m`
[image]

`# htop`
[image]

`# ps aux`
[image]

Comment: I'd appreciate a comment when you downvote. It's unconstructive otherwise.

Comment: Not my down vote but float your mouse over the down arrow -  my guess would be one of them is the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: If after a restart of a service, the same amount of memory is used, a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) can be ruled out because this results in "loss" of memory over time due to programming bugs where memory isn't freed correctly.

Second: What is your problem? You have a tiny server with 256 MB of RAM, 182 MB of which is still usable. Should you be worried about the "VIRT" number: This has nothing to do with the real amount of memory used, it's a number that includes a lof of stuff, much of which has nothing to do with real memory. Please read `man top` to learn what the numbers mean before starting to worry.

Comment: I was more worried about the %MEM, which according to the `man top` is the percentage of physical memory. All the same, I feel this answers the question nicely. Thank you very much.